# cygwin connot link .a file with main

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, cygwin

I am doing a simple library in c, I wrote my code and it is compiling. I have created an archive file .a from my library.

For testing I had created a testing file with main. The testing file is compiling but  whenever I am trying to reference my .a static library, the one I created, it is giving this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibllist
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think this means that it cannot find it as expected. 
I am using cygwin with gcc and ld.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you've solved it! `ld` can't find your `libllist.a` file. Next question; why not? Does it exist? Is `ld` looking in the right place? ...

Answer (score 0):

The `-l` switch implicitly adds the `lib` prefix and `.a` suffix to the name passed to it, so if your library is called `libllist.a`, you should reference it with `-lllist`. You also need to ensure that the library is in the library search path. See also the `-L` switch. Or you could just pass the full library name without the `-l` switch to gcc.